# In Spring MVC, where to catch Database exceptions

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, exception

[image]

I am following the structure suggested above at ( http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/ ). I tried adding a duplicate entry, which resulted in the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/cct] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry 'a@b.com' for key 'PRIMARY'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'a@b.com' for key 'PRIMARY'] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'a@b.com' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at << removed for readability>> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.bilitutor.cct.control.HomeController.signup(HomeController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    << removed for readability>>
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why is the exception being caught by the Controller ( `userService.addUser(user)` in `com.bilitutor.cct.control.HomeController` ) and not by the DAO ( `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);` ) and then bubbled up to the Controller?
2. I understand that I am getting a `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` because I am using the `@Repository` annotation, which perhaps does exception translation (correct me if I am wrong). In that case, when I catch the exception, how do I find the error code for it?
3. As a best practice, on which layer (DAO, Service or Controller) is the best spot to catch the exception?

Relevant classes :

COntroller :

```
package com.bilitutor.cct.control;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

import com.bilitutor.cct.bean.*;
import com.bilitutor.cct.service.*;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUserObect() {
      return new User();
    }

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Landing page. Just return the login.jsp
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        logger.info("home() called");
        return "login";
    }

    /**
     * Login. Either forward to the user's homepage or return back the error
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {
        logger.info("login() called");
        return "login";
    }

    /**
     * New User signup. If user already exists, send back the error, or send an email and forward to the email validation page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result) {
        logger.info("signup() : email="+user.getEmail()+" pass="+user.getPassword()+" accessCode="+user.getAccessCode());
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "login";
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.bilitutor.cct.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bilitutor.cct.dao.UserDAO;
import com.bilitutor.cct.bean.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDAO.addUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(String email) {
        userDAO.removeUser(email);
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
package com.bilitutor.cct.dao;

import com.bilitutor.cct.bean.User;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    public void removeUser(String email) {
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, email);
        if (user!=null) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception is occuring at service layer. You can see this in trace

`at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.addUser(Unknown Source)`

```
@Transactional
public void addUser(User user) {
    userDAO.addUser(user);
}
```

As previous answer says your transaction boundary is at service layer, so exception occurs there.

I would recommend to catch/throw proper business exceptions(checked exceptions) from service methods. Service methods incorporate your business logic so , if anything goes wrong it should be properly communicated to outer world through the exceptions that service methods throw. For eg : WeakPasswordException, UserNameExistsException etc

Regarding `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` try calling 
`getCause()` to see the wrapped exception

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains everything. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Quick one ... I did try to catch the Exception on Service layer, but it appears that the only place I can catch them is in the Controller, which is perhaps the first interceptor outside the Transaction Boundry. I put a try/catch block on every layer, and the debugger stopped only on the Controller layer. This now makes it impossible to catch and translate exception on Service layer!

Answer (score 0):

1.

I suspect you put your controller handler method as the transaction boundary, eg something like this:

```
@RequestMapping
@Transactional
public String myHandler(..) {
  ...
}
```

A duplicate rows can only be detected once the update is synchronized into the database, this often occurs on transaction close if you use hibernate/jpa, hence you see as if it's coming from your controller

Recall that `@Transactional` works by jdk proxy / aspect weaving.

3.

The answer depends on your business requirement. What do you need to happen when a particular exception occur?

Comment: Actually, it is my Service layer that is Transactional (I have updated the post above). Upon an Exception, I want to find out the reason for the exception (hence Question 2 in my post) and send back appropriate message (Email already exists, Password cannot be blank, etc).

Answer (score 0):

1.
I believe the exception is being caught in the controller as UserDAO.addUser() is the transactional boundary.

2.
[DataIntegrityViolationException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html) extends [NestedRuntimeException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.html) so you can use getMessage, getMostSpecificCause, getRootCause

3.
In your case above I you should catch the exception in your controller.  You want to catch exceptions at the layer where you can deal with them.  So far example if I was writing a DAO method to get a list of object.  I probably would check for the exception in the DAO and return an empty list and log the error vs throw the exception.